# ionic cordovaFile error "ENCODING_ERR"

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am working on a social app using ionic 1. I require pictures and video uploading. For pictures, everything working fine but unable to do the same for video. Here is my code:

_self.videoFromDrive = function () {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(_self.onSuccess, _self.onFail, {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO
    });
  };

_self.onSuccess = function (videoURL) {
    _self.selectedVideo = videoURL;
    _self.dpPic1 = _self.selectedVideo.substring(0, _self.selectedVideo.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    _self.dpPic2 = _self.selectedVideo.substring(_self.selectedVideo.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, _self.selectedVideo.length);
  };

_self.onFail = function (err) {
    generalService.toastMessage('Error! Someth`enter code here`ing went wrong', 'long');
  };

I am using $cordovaFile.readAsArrayBuffer(_self.dpPic1, _self.dpPic2) which fails into error

Answer (score 0):

I think There is an Issue with that Plugin. Why dont  you try

`<input type="file" id="file">`

In old Browser Android not supporting some changes. For that you may need CrossWalk.